# Get the value of an input from a button

Tags: jquery, find, jquery-selectors

Assuming I have this code :

```
...
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editCustomer"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
  </td>
  <input type="hidden" name="usr_firstname" value="Franck">
</tr>
...
```

How to get the value of `usr_firstname` input ?

I already tried a couple of things like this:

- `usr_firstname = $(this).closest('input[name="usr_firstname"]').val();`

- `usr_firstname = $(this).find('input[name="usr_firstname"]').val();`

Comment: Your HTML appears invalid... What is the parent of the hidden input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two elements are in different parts of the tree, so find the `closest` common ancestor then `find` down.

```
usr_firstname = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="usr_firstname"]').val();
```

Note: It is not valid HTML for your hidden `input` to be directly under a `TR`. Most browsers will tolerate it, but it should go elsewhere (e.g. inside the `TD`).

### Suggestion:

I would suggest you instead inject the hidden values as `data-` attributes on the rows.

```
<tr data-firstname="Franck">
  <td align="right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default editCustomer"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then the code becomes just this:

```
usr_firstname = $(this).closest('tr').data('firstname');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will move my hidden outside like you said.

Comment: Added alternate suggestion for your hidden values. `data-` attributes are the place to put extra data like that which is not displayed.

Comment: I like your approach very much.

Comment: If you need any more details. Just ask :)